# Query to return possible rows using 3 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables: A, B and C, as follows:

Table A

- ID (int) [PK]
- KeyFromTableA (varchar)

Table B

- ID (int) [PK]
- Name (varchar)

Table C

- Table_A_ID (int) [PK][FK]
- Table_B_ID (int) [PK][FK]
- ValueFromTableC (int)
- AnotherValueFromTableC (int)

I want to build a query that, by querying by a specific table B ID, returns me all possible IDs of table A that either:

- If there is at least one row that has a **Table A** `ID` and the queried **Table B** `ID`, I want to perform the operation `ValueFromTableC` - `AnotherValueFromTableC`. If this operation is positive then the current **Table A** `ID` is valid and should be returned by the query,
- If, and only IF, either the **Table A** `ID` or the **Table B** `ID` are not found within a row, I want to check Table A's `KeyFromTableA`. If such column is true, then that Table A ID is also valid and should be returned by the query.

Example

**Table A**

```
ID  |   KeyFromTableA
01    |  false
02    |  true
03    |  false
04    |  false
05 | true
```

**Table B**

```
ID | Name
1   | A
2  | B
3 | C
```

**Table C**

```
Table_A_ID | Table_B_ID | ValueFromTableC | AnotherValueFromTableC
1 | 1 | 5 | 3
1 | 2 | 3 | 6
2 | 2 | 4 | 5
3 | 1 | 0 | 1
```

If I query by `Table_B_ID` = 1 then `Table_A_ID`'s 1, 2 and 5 should be returned, because (all ordering and naming is relative to Table C):

- The first row matches `Table_B_ID` = 1, so there is a match. I perform operation 5 - 3 and it is positive. So `Table_A_ID` = 1 is valid.
- There is no `Table_B_ID` = 1 correlated with `Table_A_ID` = 2, but since in **Table A** the row with `ID` = 2 has the `KeyFromTableA` with a *true* value, `Table_A_ID` = 2 is also valid.
- There is a `Table_A_ID` = 3 that is correlated with `Table_B_ID` = 1, but it fails while performing positive check on 0 - 1. So it must not be returned.
- There is no data on **Table C** that refers to **Table A** `ID` = 4. But still the second condition must be performed, and it fails because `KeyFromTableA` is false. So it should not be returned.
- Finally, there is also no data on **Table A** `ID` = 5. The second condition is applied aswell and it passes because `KeyFromTableA` is true. So 5 should also be included in the query result.

I have this query but I can't figure why it isn't working.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id FROM b, a
LEFT JOIN c ON a.id = c.table_a_id
WHERE b.id = c.table_b_id
AND ((c.id IS NOT NULL AND c.value_from_table_c > 
c.another_value_from_table_c)
OR (c.id IS NULL AND a.key_from_table_a))
AND b.id = 1;
```

Comment: what should be the output of checked for b.id = 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple `UNION` should be enough for this.

```
SELECT id_a
    FROM table_c 
    WHERE id_b = 1
    AND col_c_1 - col_c_2 > 0
UNION 
SELECT table_a.id
    FROM table_a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_c ON (table_a.id = table_c.id_a AND table_c.id_b = 1)
    WHERE table_c.id_a IS NULL AND table_a.key_a = 'true'
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont think so we need to use table b in this case as we need just the ids from table a. Try this :

```
select a.id from a
where exists (select 1 from c where Table_B_ID = id_value(2) 
and table_a_id = a.id and c.ValueFromTableC > c.AnotherValueFromTableC)
or not exists (select 1 from c where Table_B_ID = id_value(1) 
and table_a_id = a.id) and a.KeyFromTableA;
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the input, but @anand-a 's answer is a little more readable.

Comment: yeah... not a problem :)